# How to cancel out a setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am making a boon system where the player gets a random boon/buff for 30 seconds and then it removes itself. I have the initial boon in place where it lasts 30 seconds, then removes itself. I push the boon name "Healing Boon" to a empty `player.boons = []` array.

However I am running into difficulty the other way around. Lets say the enemy wants to "debuff" my character, and REMOVE the boon instantly. Well because the countdown for my boon lasts 30 seconds, it continues to work until the 30 seconds is up, even if I give the appearance of removal. (I still keep gaining health up to 30 seconds).

I am attributing this to the `setTimeout` function. If I input 30 seconds, even if later down the line (say 5-10 seconds later), make `setTimeout = 0;` it will still continue on for the next 30 seconds. It is only on the initial 2nd attempt is `setTimeout` set to 0. But this is not what I want. I want a system that stops the boon entirely in its tracts and removes any current health buffs it gives the player.

```
function applyBoonHealing(){
    var blessedWind = setInterval(function(){
        player.cc.hp += 1;
        dom.setText("healthcounter", player.cc.hp);
    }, 1000);
    player.boons.push("Healing Boon");
    postPlayerStatusEffectImage("images/lowerstrengthicon.jpg", "buff", "0", "2", "no");
    dom.setText("healthcounter", player.cc.hp);

    setTimeout(clearBoon, 30000);
        function clearBoon(){
            clearInterval(blessedWind);
        if (player.boons.includes("Healing Boon", 0)){
            var arrayIndex = player.boons.indexOf("Healing Boon", 0);
            player.boons.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
        }           
            dom.setText("healthcounter", player.cc.hp);
            postPlayerStatusEffectImage("images/lowerstrengthicon.jpg", "buff", "0", "2", "yes");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clearTimeout() method is solution to this problem:

```
var boonHandle = setTimeout(clearBoon, 30000);
(...)
clearTimeout(boonHandle); //To cancel your timer
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **clearTimeout()** method,

```
var mySetTimeoutFunc = setTimeout(clearBoon, 30000);
```

to stop this you will just have to `clearTimeout(mySetTimeoutFunc);`

for more info see this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout_cleartimeout2

Answer (score 0):

**clearTimeout** is a event to stop Timeout, see below

```
function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```